# Connect Four Win Check Not Working

Tags: java, fonts

So I have been working on my final term project which is a Connect Four game. I ran into this issue where i believe my CheckWin logic should work, put is providing me with no output when i run the program. I have my CheckWin() being called in my actionPerformed and I am stuck as to what to do here. As a side note, is there any way to easily increase the size of text inside of a JButton? I would like to increase the size of the "X's" and "O's".  I am relatively new at programming so sorry if these are simple fixes. My code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Connect implements ActionListener {





private JFrame window = new JFrame();    
private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel myPanelB = new JPanel();
private JButton[][] myButtons = new JButton[6][7];
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[7];
private boolean win = false;

private int count = 5;
private int count2 = 5;
private int count3 = 5;
private int count4 = 5;
private int count5 = 5;
private int count6 = 5;
private int count7 = 5;
private int countA = 0;
private String letter = "";

public boolean checkHorizontalWin(String letter) {
for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length; y++) {
    // going to length-3 to avoid IndexOutOfBounds exception
    for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length - 3; x++) {
        if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 1].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 2].getText().equals(letter)
            && myButtons[y][x + 3].getText().equals(letter)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}


public boolean checkVerticalWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkDiagonalToTheLeftWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < myButtons[y].length - 3; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x + 1].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x + 2].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x + 3].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean checkDiagonalToTheRightWin(String letter) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myButtons.length - 3; y++) {
        for (int x = 3; x < myButtons[y].length; x++) {
            if (myButtons[y][x].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 1][x - 1].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 2][x - 2].getText().equals(letter)
                && myButtons[y + 3][x - 3].getText().equals(letter)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}



public Connect(){
    window.setSize(800,700);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,7));
    myPanelB.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i ++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        myPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j ++){
            myButtons[i][j] = new JButton();
            myPanelB.add(myButtons[i][j]);
        }
    }
    window.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    window.add(myPanelB, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    countA++;
    if (countA % 2 == 0)
        letter = "X";
    else
        letter = "O";



    if (e.getSource() == buttons[0]){
        myButtons[count][0].setText(letter);
        count --;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[1]){
        myButtons[count2][1].setText(letter);
        count2 --;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[2]){
        myButtons[count3][2].setText(letter);
        count3--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[3]){
        myButtons[count4][3].setText(letter);
        count4--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[4]){
        myButtons[count5][4].setText(letter);
        count5--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[5]){
        myButtons[count6][5].setText(letter);
        count6--;
    }
    if (e.getSource() == buttons[6]){
        myButtons[count7][6].setText(letter);
        count7--;
    }
    if (myButtons[0][0].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][0].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][1].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][1].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][2].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][2].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][3].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][3].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][4].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][4].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][5].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][5].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    }
    if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);


    if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")){
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);

    if (checkHorizontalWin(letter)
        || checkVerticalWin(letter)
        || checkDiagonalToTheLeftWin(letter)
        || checkDiagonalToTheRightWin(letter)
    ) {
        win = true;

    if (win == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " has won!");
        System.exit(0);
    }    
    }





    }  




    if(win == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " has won!");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if(count == 42 && win == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "tie game");
        System.exit(0);
    }            


    }

}



public static void main(String[] args){
    new Connect();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identation helps.

```
if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X"))
{
    buttons[6].setEnabled(false);

    // Missing brace on previous if
    // checkXWin methods only invoked inside the above if-statement.
    if (checkHorizontalWin(letter)
        || checkVerticalWin(letter)
        || checkDiagonalToTheLeftWin(letter)
        || checkDiagonalToTheRightWin(letter)
        ) {
            win = true;

            if (win == true) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " has won!");
                ystem.exit(0);
            }    
        }
    }
```

You haven't closed a brace in one of your if statements properly in the actionPerformed method. As a result, your program will only check for a win once the last column is full.

It also seems the condition `if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")` is repeated twice. That wouldn't be the cause of your issue but I think you might want to remove one of those statements.

Comment: thank you! I was beating myself up over something so simple, sorry I didn't realize that earlier. As a side note, do you know how I can increase the font size of my X's and O's? I don't have an idea of how to go about increasing font size in a JButton.

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets on your if statements are incorrectly placed.

```
 if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")){
    buttons[6].setEnabled(false);


 if (myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("O") || myButtons[0][6].getText().equals("X")){
    buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
```

On both of theses `if` statements you have opening brackets but the closing brackets do not come until the end of the `actionPerformed` method.

This means the code to check for a winner does not get executed unless both of these conditions resulted in true, which  is not what you want and I'm pretty sure is impossible...